# How to redirect to a new page in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My interceptor assigned to all uri that starts with "shop/shopping"

```
mapping path="/shop/shopping"
```

and 
i have this in my servlet.xml :

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
```

and i have this in my interceptor:

```
String id = (String) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
    String sessionId = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("JSESSIONID");
    if (sessionId == null || !sessionId.equals(id)) {
        response.sendRedirect("redirect:/index");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

it doesn't work. if i use just

```
response.sendRedirect("index");
```

it tries to find index page in /shop/index, but i want just clear path with "index"

Comment: have you tried response.sendRedirect("/index"); yet?

Comment: ok i'm just dumb. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `response.sendRedirect("/index");` should solve the problem. That will make the server use the absolute path instead of the relative.

*Just answering this again to make sure the question is not marked as unanswered.*